# Would Apple reject an app because of using cookies?

Tags: ios, cookies, appstore-approval

Would Apple reject a native app because it stores cookies send back and forth to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Cookie are *the* normal way to maintain sessions to a server over HTTP, and there is nothing in the app store rules to forbid them (would be absurd if there were... though admittedly *some* of the app store rules *are* weird;-).

Comment: Further to this, if you have the singleton `NSHTTPCookieStorage` in play then `NSURLConnection` will store and transmit cookies for you automatically.